# Model.fit Value Error (Text Classification Model)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need your help please...

I am trying go get the following Text Classification Module working:

```py
     # Train and validate model.
    history = model.fit(x_train,
            train_labels,
            epochs=epochs,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            validation_data=(x_val, val_labels),
            verbose=2,
            batch_size=batch_size) # Logs once per epoch.
```

[Source File Can be Found Here: Google - Git Hub Text Classification Code](https://github.com/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/guides/text_classification/train_ngram_model.py)

However I am getting the following error on execution:

```sh
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_ngram_model.py", line 113, in <module>
    train_ngram_model(data)
  File "train_ngram_model.py", line 93, in train_ngram_model
    batch_size=batch_size) # Logs once per epoch.
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 593, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 646, in _process_inputs
    x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2383, in _standardize_user_data
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2428, in _standardize_tensors
    converted_x.append(_convert_scipy_sparse_tensor(a, b))
  File "C:\Users\joebloggs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 3198, in _convert_scipy_sparse_tensor
    raise ValueError('A SciPy sparse matrix was passed to a model '
ValueError: A SciPy sparse matrix was passed to a model that expects dense inputs. Please densify your inputs first, such as by calling `x.toarray()`.
```

I have spent several hours now to find a solution, and I haven't gotten anywhere.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Have you downloaded the dataset `http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz`?

Comment: Hi - Yes I have. I was able to successfully write my own "Main" (i.e. __name__ == '__main__') file and get everything  working until the last Module (train_ngram_model.py); which I then realised was the Main file anyway. I tried to run the "train_ngram_model.py" file and it through up the referenced error.